# Problems with external monitors on Debian 11 Bullseye (KDE Plasma)

Tags: debian, multi-monitor

I have a Dell Precision 3560 laptop that is running Debian 11 Bullseye with KDE/Plasma in clamshell mode (ie., the laptop lid closed) with 2 external Dell2408WFP monitors (which are quite old but I've never had any other problems with them)

The problem is that after the monitors go to sleep (after 360min) almost always, they fail to wake up, and I have to open up the laptop and press the power button which then brings it and the monitors back to life.

With a different laptop (but the same monitors) I don't have this problem. The setting (360min) appears to be the longest possible setting (there is no "never" option).

On the other laptop, pressing  on the external keyboard brings it back to life, and this also sometimes works with the problematic Dell.

I was hoping there is a setting in a config file where I can override the 360min setting:

[image]

either to "never" or some larger value? Or any other help would be much appreciated.